# How to change SQLDeveloper's language to Chinese?

Tags: oracle-11g, sqldeveloper, oracle-10g, oracle-database

I've seen many posts on how to change SQLDeveloper's language to English, by using the following method:

```
sqldeveloper.exe --AddVMOption=-Duser.language=en
```

I have tried this method with both English (en) and French (fr) but it does not work for Chinese. I have tried zh_CN, zh_cn, zh_TW, zh_tw, but they all will eventually show the following error message, after opening a connection:

```
Local not recognized
Vendor code 17176
```

Using `zh` does not produce this error, but it also doesn't do anything.

In the ide/bin/ide.boot file, I see the following line:

```
oracle.translated.locales = de,es,fr,it,ja,ko,pt_BR,zh_CN,zh_TW
```

which made he hopeful zh_CN would work, but it did not.

How can I configure SQLDeveloper to use Chinese?

Comment: Extremely relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768313/how-can-i-change-the-language-to-english-in-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: Google is amazing!

Comment: You don’t specify what OS you are running.  It might appear your issue is an underlying Oracle issue with [Asian languages](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2173448).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to my sqldeveloper short cut:

```
sqldeveloperW.exe --AddVMOption=-Duser.language=zh --AddVMOption=-Duser.country=CN
```

The trick here is that `-Duser.language=zh` does not suffice. For other languages, like French and Russian, you do not need to specify `-Duser.country`.